# ¿Para que sirve el memset?

Tags: c

Pero la verdad no se que función realiza el memset().

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int data_processed;
    int file_pipes[2];
    const char some_data[] = "123";
    char buffer [BUFSIZ + 1];
    pid_t fork_result;

    memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
    if (pipe(file_pipes) == 0){
        fork_result = fork();
        if(fork_result == -1){
            fprintf(stderr, "Fork failure");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (fork_result == 0) {
            data_processed = read(file_pipes[0], buffer, BUFSIZ);
            printf("Read %d bytes: %s \n", data_processed, buffer);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }   
        else {
        data_processed = write(file_pipes[1], some_data, strlen(some_data));
        printf("Wrote %d bytes \n", data_processed);
        }
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: has leido la documentacion ?  Pon el codigo como texto y no como imagen. Puedes darle formato con `ctrl + k`

Comment: [`mem`ory `set`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset). Traducido como establecer memoria. Establece la memoria a un valor determinado... tal y como su nombre indica.

Comment: Si la leí pero solo explica sobre pipe, pero no sobre el memset, listo ya subí el codigo

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster la verdad es que la traducción automática a español es bastante ridícula... Luis, prueba a leer la documentación original en ingles

Comment: Gracias, tenias razón la traducción es una basura

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> La función memset de C ***memset(void *str, int c, size_t n)** copia el caracter **c** (un char sin signo) a los primeros **n** caracteres de **str**.

Aquí un ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
     char str[50];

     strcpy(str,"This is string.h library function");
     puts(str);

     memset(str,'$',7);
     puts(str);

     return(0);
}
```

Y lo que se muestra por pantalla:

```
This is string.h library function
$$$$$$$ string.h library function
```

En tu caso, sustituye los elementos del buffer por `'\0'`

Comment: Gracias Hector por la información

Comment: @LuisAngelLópezSantos Si la respuesta te ha ayudado y la consideras útil por favor marca la señal de aceptación para indicarlo. Hacer esto indica que aceptas la respuesta como la que mejor te ha servido y le da puntos de reputación al autor, que es la forma en que se agradece en SO.